# Does Installing a driver increase linux kernel memory footprint?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kernel, linux-kernel

I have read that linux kernel is monolithic kernel and it contains drivers within it, in a single file.

For example, I have two linux kernels 3.16.0.40 and 3.16.0.50 Currently booted system with 3.16.0.40 and installed for e.g nvidia driver

Does the driver is pushed in a kernel ?

If so, If I select 3.16.0.50 from grub and boot a system

Can it access the currently installed driver from previous kernel?

does switching between linux kernels affect the software which needs that driver?

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking. You ask two different things in the title and in the text. But see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

The Linux kernel has a feature called **Loadable Kernel Modules (LKM)**.

As the drivers are usually built as kernel modules, I use the two terms "drivers" and "modules" interchangeably. The modules are the files ending with `*.ko` (kernel objects). They are usually located in a sub-folder below `/lib/modules`.

- **To answer your title-question: (increase in kernel footprint)**

  A kernel that has all the modules/drivers built-in, does not increase the memory footprint during runtime. All is loaded at boot up. If the driver(s) are kernel-modules they may be loaded later, ant thus increase the kernel footprint at a later stage.

  When you compare the file size of a kernel with all drivers built-in and a kernel with modules, the one with the modules is smaller. The size of the modules is the difference.
- **The text question: (access drivers from previous kernel)**

  No, this is not possible. Each driver/module needs to be build for the exact kernel that it has to run under. For this reason you will see a directory with the kernel name under the modules root path `/lib/modules`.

There is more information in [Linux loadable kernel modules HOWTO](http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Module-HOWTO/). A good way to learn more about kernel and modules is to build a kernel yourself. It is not as difficult as it sounds. There are tutorials [for Ubuntu](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel) and for [stock kernels](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2013/06/compile-linux-kernel/). (you probably find more tutorials if you google).

Answer (score 1):

The Kernel is compiled prior to installation on a system, so in a since its size is set in stone. Drivers and any other modules or programs will not affect the size of the kernel. **Only recompiling the kernel would change its size.**

That's why there are so many versions of Linux. Small to huge. Some are compiled to work without a GUI interface at all in order to be small and lean for projects that only need a terminal connection like the IOT (Internet Of Things). Some have custom GUI's, like Ubuntu and RedHat etc.

You may have the option to choose the GUI, Gnome or KDE. But that is like the options on a car. You can change the paint and add leather seats, but it is still a 4 cylinder under the hood.